# hide (toggle) nested list using jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I use JQuery to do the following with the below HTML:

I want to hide/toggle `1.1, 1.2` after clicking `1` , and likewise
I want to hide/toggle `2.1, 2.2` after clicking `2` .

```
<ul>
<li> 1   </li>
    <ul>
    <li> 1.1 </li>
    <li> 1.2 </li>
    </ul>
<li> 2 </li>
    <ul>
    <li> 2.1 </li>
    <li> 2.2 </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I have not had success with the following?

```
$("li").click(function() {
        $(this).children("ul").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The only legal child of an `ul` is an `li`, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sdbU3/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try `next` rather than `children()`

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
});​
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/7JPf6/2/)